# QGIS 2.18 + Mac OSX sierra crashes and slow

Tags: qgis, osx

I've been using QGis for quite a few years on Mac OSX, never had a problem.
Now with the current configuration of OSX Sierra + QGIS 2.18.1 many project files that ones were opening nice and smooth became quite a problem to manage.

Opening project files takes quite some time and the software crashes all the time in two conditions: when I switch on some layer or while zoomin in or out. I also tried to downgreade to QGIS 2.14.10-1 but I still experienced the same.

The problem occours on different machines (MacBook Pro, iMac) and different users. We also tried different project files of different sizes. Is anybody else experiencing the same?

Comment: What install method are you using? I'd suggest trying the homebrew install and see if that helps.

Comment: Same here. QGIS 2.18 crashes often on my OSSierra macbook, mostly when dealing with aspect properties of vector layers (particularly when applying a graduated fill)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/114453)

Comment: Tried anything. It seems more of a OSX compatibility issue. Same project file on windows runs smoothly. I'm trying to report a general experience on a year usage now. QGis on MAC seems to run just slow and buggy no matter what. I see layers with 6000 points making my mac crash or run slow and my 30+ students using not-so-powerful Windows laptops running the same file like a charm.

Comment: My QGIS 2.18 was crashing before it even started, till I heeded this suggestion in the readme: “If you have an old QGIS.app in your Applications folder, trash it before installing QGIS 2.16. Old files may not be deleted by the installer, which may cause problems for QGIS 2.16.” (The readme wasn’t updated since 2.16, this is actually for 2.18.)